# Hide/unhide rows with a check box

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a sheet where I need to hide / unhide rows based on whether or not the box is checked, I currently have the following code

```
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
If CheckBox3 = True Then
[75:86].EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else: [75:86].EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Which hides unhides Rows 75:86, however I wish to unhide/hide rows 75:86 AND rows 100:125
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
If CheckBox3 = True Then
[75:86].EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else: 
[75:86].EntireRow.Hidden = True
[100:125].EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```